# Using buttons in gridmvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I'm currently using `GridMvc` to display a list on an Ajax view using this code:

```
columns.Add()
 .Titled("Host").Filterable(true).Encoded(false)
 .Sanitized(false)
 .RenderValueAs(LogonEvents => Html.ActionLink(LogonEvents.Host, 
     "Computers", new { computerName = LogonEvents.Host, 
                        userName = LogonEvents.Name, 
                        onclick = "showPageLoadingMessage()" }));
```

I'd like to use buttons rather than an `ActionLink` but I'm not sure how to pass the values to the next view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just keep it simple and apply a CSS class to the `htmlAttributes` object.

```
Html.ActionLink("Button Name", "Index", null, new { @class="classname" })
```

and then create a class in your stylesheet

```
a.classname
{
   background: url(../Images/image.gif) no-repeat top left;
   display: block;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
}
```

Or code your own [HTML Helper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/787320/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-HTML-Helpers-and).